# Scroll jquery animation missing div

Tags: jquery, css, animation, scroll

I got a scrool animation pointing to 'step 2' but the animation goes all the way to 'step 3'. Although my link to step 3 seems to work with the same function.
I can't figure out why it doesn't stop at the right div, thanks for the help!

here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style>
.out{background:gray;height:300px;}
.box{height:300px;overflow:auto;}
.question1{background:red;height:300px;}
.question2{background:green;height:300px;}
.question3{background:blue;height:300px;}
.question4{background:yellow;height:300px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="out">
    here
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="question1" id="step1"> 
        step 1<br>
        <a href="#step2">Step 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="question2" id="step2">
        step 2<br>
        <a href="#step3">step 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="question3" id="step3">
        step 3
    </div>
    <div class="question4" id="step4">
        step 4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="out">
    here
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){  
        var the_id = $(this).attr("href");  
        $('.box').animate({  
            scrollTop:$(the_id).offset().top  
        }, 'slow');  
        return false;  
    });  

});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reasons sems to be the missing semi-colon after $(the_id).position().top; I put you code into jsfiddle and it works fine for me in ie & firefox now : http://jsfiddle.net/HZTDE/1/

```
scrollTop:$(the_id).offset().top;
```

It probably has to do with automatic semi-colon insertion - quote from *"JavaScript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford. Copyright 2008 Yahoo! Inc., 978-0-596-51774-8."*:

> JavaScript has a mechanism that tries to correct faulty programs by automatically inserting semicolons. Do not depend on this. It can mask more serious errors. It sometimes inserts semicolons in places where they are not welcome. Consider the consequences of semicolon insertion on the return statement. If a return statement returns a value, that value expression must begin on the same line as the return:

Comment: do you know how to keep the animation please?

Comment: you're right and without the semi-colon it seemed to recalculate the offsets on the fly so as a suggestion, here's an adapted version which works in firefox and ie (haven'tried the others); basically the idea is to save the original offsets at the time of loading; http://jsfiddle.net/HZTDE/3/

Comment: That's great my friend, just what i needed, thank you!
may the force be with you !

Answer (score 0):

You are placing your divs and anchors incorrectly!

Also, depending on how you positioned your html, you could try to use `$(the_id).position().top + 'px'`

.position() gets the offset relevant to the parent's bounds, whereas offset() uses the document's bounds.

Comment: can you show me how tp place my div/anchors please?
http://jsfiddle.net/yv6Rt/394/